# Error adding WCF Service to .NET Core 2.2 REST API

Tags: wcf, .net-core, connected-services

We are porting our Windows Mobile handheld terminals to Android hence we need to change our WCF services. I am currently writing proxies to convert WCF services to REST APIs using .NET Core (2.2)

I have created a .NET Core 2.2 API project and trying to add my WCF service as a Connected Service. But when I try to add my WCF service I get the following error :

[image]

I made a search about the error and found that logs can be found at "C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService" folder. I have examined the files and found no information to help the issue.

WCFConnectedServiceLog.txt:

```
[10/24/2019 15:35:40],6,Importing web service metadata ...
[10/24/2019 15:35:40],49,Number of service endpoints found: 1
[10/24/2019 15:35:40],47,Scaffolding service reference code ...
[10/24/2019 15:35:40],92,Executing command [C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet new console --no-restore --force --type project --language C# --output . --name svcutil_starter"
[10/24/2019 15:35:51],90,Executing command [C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet restore --ignore-failed-sources"
[10/24/2019 15:35:52],92,Executing command [C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet svcutil --additionalprobingpath "C:\Users\{username}\.nuget\packages" "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\SvcUtilParams.txt""
[10/24/2019 15:36:02],53,Restoring NuGet packages for bootstrapper ...
[10/24/2019 15:36:06],26,Building bootstrapper project ...
[10/24/2019 15:36:10],5,Invoking bootstrapper ...
[10/24/2019 15:36:11],26,The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
[10/24/2019 15:36:11],96,An error occurred in the tool.
[10/24/2019 15:36:11],42,Done.
```

SvcUtilParams.txt :

```
"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\wsdl\tempuri.org.wsdl" 
"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\wsdl\MazotService.Objects.xsd" 
"C:\Users\{username\\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\wsdl\noNamespace.xsd" 
"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\wsdl\schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd" 
"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\wsdl\tempuri.org.xsd" 
-nl
-v Minimal
-elm
-tml Infrastructure
-npu
-nrr
-o "Reference"
-d "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40"
-bd "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2019_Oct_24_15_35_40\svcutil_bootstrap"
-cn en-US
-n "*,ServiceReference1"
-ct "System.Array"
-ct "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
-r "System.Runtime, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, *}"
-r "System.Collections, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, *}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore, {Microsoft.AspNetCore, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Views.V3, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Views.V4, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json, 1.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, {Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common, 2.8.0}"
-r "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, 2.8.0}"
-r "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.CSharp, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, {Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, 2.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, {Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer, {Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml, {Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, 2.1.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter, {Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks, {Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite, {Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded, {Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, {Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, {Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, {Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Http, {Microsoft.Extensions.Http, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, {Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, {Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization, {Microsoft.Extensions.Localization, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource, {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, {Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Options, {Microsoft.Extensions.Options, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, {Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations, {Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, {Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders, {Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml, {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Xml, 5.3.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, {Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.VisualBasic, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "Microsoft.Win32.Registry, {Microsoft.Win32.Registry, 4.5.0}"
-r "mscorlib, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "netstandard, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "Newtonsoft.Json, {Newtonsoft.Json, 11.0.2}"
-r "Newtonsoft.Json.Bson, {Newtonsoft.Json.Bson, 1.0.1}"
-r "Remotion.Linq, {Remotion.Linq, 2.2.0}"
-r "System, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.AppContext, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Buffers, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Collections.Concurrent, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Collections.Immutable, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Collections.NonGeneric, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Collections.Specialized, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Configuration, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Console, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Core, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Data, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Data.Common, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Data.SqlClient, {System.Data.SqlClient, 4.6.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.Contracts, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.Debug, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.Process, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.Tools, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Drawing, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Drawing.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Dynamic.Runtime, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Globalization, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Globalization.Calendars, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Globalization.Extensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, {System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, 5.3.0}"
-r "System.Interactive.Async, {System.Interactive.Async, 3.2.0}"
-r "System.IO, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.Compression, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.Compression.Brotli, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.FileSystem, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.IsolatedStorage, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.Pipelines, {System.IO.Pipelines, 4.5.2}"
-r "System.IO.Pipes, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Linq, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Linq.Expressions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Linq.Parallel, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Linq.Queryable, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Memory, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Http, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Http.Formatting, {Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, 5.2.6}"
-r "System.Net.HttpListener, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Mail, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.NameResolution, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.NetworkInformation, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Ping, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Requests, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Security, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.ServicePoint, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.Sockets, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebClient, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebProxy, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebSockets, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebSockets.Client, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProtocol, {System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProtocol, 4.5.1}"
-r "System.Numerics, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Numerics.Vectors, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ObjectModel, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.DispatchProxy, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Emit, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Extensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Metadata, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Resources.Reader, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Resources.ResourceManager, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Resources.Writer, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 4.5.1}"
-r "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Extensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Handles, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.InteropServices, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Loader, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Numerics, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Serialization, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.AccessControl, {System.Security.AccessControl, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Security.Claims, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, {System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Csp, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, {System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Security.Permissions, {System.Security.Permissions, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Security.Principal, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Security.Principal.Windows, {System.Security.Principal.Windows, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Security.SecureString, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ServiceModel.Web, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ServiceProcess, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Text.Encoding, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Text.Encodings.Web, {System.Text.Encodings.Web, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Text.RegularExpressions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Channels, {System.Threading.Channels, 4.5.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Overlapped, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Tasks, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Thread, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.ThreadPool, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Threading.Timer, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Transactions, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Transactions.Local, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.ValueTuple, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Web, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Web.HttpUtility, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Windows, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.Linq, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.Serialization, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.XDocument, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.XmlDocument, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.XmlSerializer, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.XPath, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "System.Xml.XPath.XDocument, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-r "WindowsBase, {Microsoft.NETCore.App, 2.2.0}"
-tf "netcoreapp2.2"
```

How can I fix the issue, what else should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer here: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3383#issuecomment-463747870

This works for me.
My project was .net core 2.1 and I had.net core 2.2 and 3 installed on my machine. I couldn't add a WCF reference to my project with the same issue and when I ran `dotnet --version` result was 3.0.100

I  looked into versions that I have by running `dotnet --info` I picked the latest .net core 2.1 that I had and ran this command `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.1.509`

509 is the latest SDK version of 2.1 that I have on my machine.

So now I can add the WCFreference to my project.

Answer (score 1):

create a new .net Standard project to hold the service. the service does not work in a api/web project

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to do this conversion since the Asp.Net core is not well compatible with WCF. we can directly create Rest API by using WCF created by Webhttpbinding. Only WCF created by Basichttpbinding could be referenced correctly in the Core project. Therefore, I would like to know how does the WCF on the server-side created, which binding does the server use?
Besides, cleaning up your project and referencing WCF again can sometimes be useful.
You can check the support state for the Asp.Net Core project in the below repository `issues`.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
Alternatively, we could simply create WCF Rest API by using Webhttpbinding.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a case. Our devices will communicate with SAP RFCs, which DotNetConnector for .NET Core are unavailable. We should use WCF services to communicate with SAP. Then why not use WCF services instead of REST API is a technology choice.

Comment: Asp.Net WebAPI based on the Dotnet framework might be a choice.  it completely supported calling the WCF service by a client proxy. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: That might be an easier choice but porting new Android services to .NET Core Framework was the choice made and I had to follow the path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .NET Core 3.0 preview sdk installed? Try running dotnet --version on the command line to see if 3.0 preview is the sdk being used.

I was able to reproduce this after installing the .NET Core 3.0 preview on my machine. This looks like a bug in the tool where we aren't using the target framework of your project correctly, and instead use whatever target framework is the default for your current sdk (e.g. when a project is created using "dotnet new"). I'll investigate how to fix this and update this thread once we can get it fixed.

For now, I was able to work around this by specifying an older sdk version in a global.json at the root of my drive. To do this just open an admin command prompt in the C:\ directory and run:
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.104

Replace the version with whatever 2.2 version you have installed. You can check this with dotnet --info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, dotnet core 3.0 preview was the exact problem! My problem started around christmas and I found out .netcore preview 3.0 was installed on the 19th of Dec... once I uninstalled it, problem went away and WCF imports started working again.

Comment: P.S. I'm also on VS 2017.. apparently this issue was fixed for VS2019 but have not been retrospectively fixed for 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Using dotnet core 2.1 and visual studio 2017

```
 <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

In Web and API it is not working But once added new dotnet standard  2.0 library. There added service reference  It worked for me.